# Prevent MailItem.Reply from opening Inspector window in Outlook 2010?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am building a shared-addin for Outlook.

Inside the code, I am creating a reply email using `MailItem.Reply()` method 
and discarding it later. I am using this to get the sender email address 
for emails coming through Exchange server.

It was working fine for Outlook 2007. 
But for Outlook 2010, the Reply method seems to opening the mail editor window.

I am on windows 7.

Is there any way to suppress that window or write seperate code based on Outlook version?

Comment: Please ask the "real question" in the title. Yes, it's possible to detect OL version, but more interesting is *why* is `Reply` opening up a new Inspector window? (Also, detecting the version *gains nothing* unless there is a work-about for a specific version.)

Comment: I apologize for the misleading title. Yes, I agree with your comment.

Comment: I don't remember this (an implicit Display) occurring, and it is not documented/noted to do so as far as I can tell; could it be a side-effect of some other code? (That is, can this be reproduced in an add-in that *only* uses `MailItem.Reply`? e.g on initialize, "Reply" to the first message in the Inbox)

Comment: Please can you help me See the below post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911177/shared-add-ins-for-outlook-2007-capturing-replytoall-event/14914107#14914107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on discarding the message - don't create it to begin with (*don't use `Reply()` unless you intend on sending the message*). You can use the [`Recipient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipient.aspx) class to resolve an Exchange users email address with minimal resource utilization.

```cs
string senderEmail = string.Empty;
Outlook.Recipient recipient = mailItem.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(mailItem.SenderEmailAddress);
if (recipient != null && recipient.Resolve() && recipient.AddressEntry != null) 
{
    Outlook.ExchangeUser exUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
    if (exUser != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress))
       senderEmail = exUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

Comment: nice suggestion! I will try it and let you know.